# How do I make this pandas function faster?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, big-o

I'm trying to make a function that solves for n in this equation (and then p, q and r) [Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clxwc.png). x, y, z, are known. It used binary search, to try to find n with a tolerance of +-0.0001

```py
# game is a series with implied probabilites for each outcome in a football match
def logfunc(game):
    n_range = [1, 0]
    n = 0.5
    probs = 1 / game
        
    expression = (probs ** (1/n)).sum()
    while not math.isclose(expression, 1, abs_tol=0.0001):
        if expression > 1:
            n_range[0] = n
        else:
            n_range[1] = n 
            
        n = (n_range[0] + n_range[1]) / 2
        expression = (probs ** (1/n)).sum()
            
        
    return game[ODDS] ** (1/n)
```

I was able to come up with this but it's painfully slow (on a dataframe with about 300000 rows)

Bonus question: :)
binary search has big O of O(log n). what is n in this function? Is it number of numbers between 0 and 1 at 0.0001 intervals?

Comment: Hi, could you give an example input with corresponding output?

Comment: Of course :) input: `pd.Series([1.73, 3.5, 5], index=["home_odds", "draw_odds", "away_odds"])` output: `pd.Series([1.794, 3.804, 5.564], index=["home_odds", "draw_odds", "away_odds"])` I also forgot to mention what the ODDS variable is. `ODDS = ["home_odds", "draw_odds", "away_odds"]`

Comment: Thanks!  What are the exact outputs with that input now, and what would *should* the outputs be?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original comment. It now shows the corresponding output :)

Comment: `n` is missing for this function. What is its value?

Comment: oops. n = 0.5 :)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention `ODDS` which is also missing ;) .

Answer (score 0):

On big issue is that working with Pandas series is generally slow. A faster alternative is to work with Numpy arrays (that Pandas uses internally). Numpy arrays are not labelled like series so one need to adapt the `game[ODDS]` expression if `ODDS` is not an integer (the index of the label must be computed in this case). You can use Numpy array by just adding the line `np_game = game.to_numpy()` and replace the variable `game` by `np_game`. This is 25 times faster on my machine. If this is not enough, then you can use Numba so to speed up the computation (since it can remove the overhead of calling Numpy functions). This should be at least 1 order of magnitude faster.

> binary search has big O of O(log n). what is n in this function? Is it number of numbers between 0 and 1 at 0.0001 intervals?

Not exactly. It would be true if the convergence check was directly based on `n` but this is not the case. The check is based on the convergence of `(probs ** (1/n)).sum()` and this expression does not behave linearly at all. For example, for the provided input, we get `0.456` for `n=0.5`, `0.120` for `n=0.25` and `0.013` for `n=0.125`. Note that the last value is divided by ~10 while `n` is divided by `2` while it was only divided by ~4 for the prior step. I expect this computation to converge with an exponential rate initially and be found in `O((log n)**k)` where `k` is a constant that is a bit hard to find (certainly >=1), and where `n` is indeed number of numbers between 0 and 1 at 0.0001 intervals. The reason is that the range has a size that is divided by 2 for every step and one can approximate the computed expression by a polynomial function. When the range becomes very small, I expect the function to be smooth and even pseudo linear so the binary search should be pretty efficient for the last steps and `k` should be a small constant >=1 unless `probs` is carefully chosen so not to converge (it should certainly be very unlikely to happen with random values and probably even real-world ones).

Comment: Thank you. It now takes about 1 minute instead of 10 minutes! As for O, ok that was a bit more complicated than I initially thought. Just to make sure, you're not saying that `O((log n)**k)` is the answer, right? This is just the initial rate?.